# Gitlab Runner Error: Failed to upload artifacts

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

In `config.toml` for the runner settings, we have `tls_verify=false` set, so ideally, it shouldn't be checking for the cert, and can use a self-signed certificate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ERROR:**

```
public/dist: found 38 matching artifact files and directories 
untracked: found 36 files                          
ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... error  error=couldn't execute POST against https://internalgitlab.corp/api/v4/jobs/6059/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive&expire_in=90+minutes: Post "https://internalgitlab.corp/api/v4/jobs/6059/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive&expire_in=90+minutes": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority id=6059 token=BDqtpUa7
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... error  error=couldn't execute POST against https://internalgitlab.corp/api/v4/jobs/6059/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive&expire_in=90+minutes: Post "https://internalgitlab.corp/api/v4/jobs/6059/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive&expire_in=90+minutes": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority id=6059 token=BDqtpUa7
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... error  error=couldn't execute POST against https://internalgitlab.corp/api/v4/jobs/6059/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive&expire_in=90+minutes: Post "https://internalgitlab.corp/api/v4/jobs/6059/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive&expire_in=90+minutes": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority id=6059 token=BDqtpUa7
FATAL: invalid argument                            
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```